# Parse query "sometimes" never returns and will freeze app. Sometimes completes very quickly

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am querying items for a news feed and usually the query fires fine (in milliseconds) and populates my news feed fine. Other times, it will freeze the app and not return anything.

In the simulator, what happens is that when the query fires, the network indicator will endlessly spin and using break points, I see that the query never returns (using `findObjectsInBackground`). At this point Xcode does not show any network activity itself, just the spinning network indicator in the simulator.  The weirdest thing is that about 50% of the time it completes fine. My code is below:

```
PFQuery *query = [Item query];
[query includeKey:@"place"];
[query includeKey:@"place.createdBy"];
[query includeKey:@"owner"];
[query whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"userDeleted"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query setLimit:20];
// self.newsFeedItems = [query findObjects];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (objects) {
        self.newsFeedItems = objects;
        if (completionHandler) {completionHandler(nil);}
    }
}];
```

`Item` is a subclass of PFObject, I query and save these in several places in my app no problem. `place` is a pointer to a different class, `place.createdBy` is a User object on the place object. This seems like a very simple query, only 20 items at that. I used the synchronous call to see if any additional information is reported but when it freezes it will just lock up the app.

Any help appreciated if you see issues with my query. Thanks. This is in a method with a completion handler hence the completionHandler line.

Comment: Is the query freezing on the client side (iOS app) or server side (Parse)? Take a look at the Parse browser and go to the Analytics section, then go to Slow Queries. If the query is successfully executing in the appropriate amount of time, then we can narrow down the problem to something within the app or possibly strange behavior with the simulator

Comment: I've looked at Parse Slow Queries, nothing too helpful. Only a couple lines show up and they have slow % of 0.0 and median times are in the milliseconds. On further investigation now I see that when I force this query with a synch call- the app will lock up 100%. The query does fire and return, but locks up right when other queries are called. Somehow this is affecting other queries or objects.

Comment: If you force the query to be performed synchronously you will block the main thread which also handles the UI, which will be guaranteed to lock up your app until the query is finished. It sounds like the query is being performed correctly on the backend, so the problem lies in how it's being handled. Could you elaborate more on what you mean by the query does fire and return, but locks up when other queries are called? Is the issue with the above code or elsewhere? Make sure you are not blocking the main thread at any point

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do synch query in the delegate just for testing purposes...I know the app will lock up with that temporarily. After more testing I'm seeing more bizarre things. I'll comment out the news feed query, the app launches fine but the network indicator shows endlessly (a parse query did not finish correctly?). After clicking around a few tabs (tab bar app), suddenly the app will totally freeze with no error messages in Xcode. I need to do more digging and come back because there may be a bigger issue. Most confusing is that the freeze only happens 50% of the time.

Comment: Don't ever do a synchronous query, especially in the app delegate of all places. Remove all of your synchronous queries and see if the problem persists. If there's still an issue, try to comment out queries until you can narrow it down to the problem

Comment: I strung some `findInBackground` queries together (with completion handlers) since I thought maybe Parse was having issues dealing with all the threads. Even with that, the news feed query failure rate is about 50%. Is the query especially complicated for parse to deal with? all of the `includeKey`s? Even going two tables away with the `includeKey:@"place.createdBy"` line.

Comment: Nope, the query complexity of the query (i.e. number of constraints such as whereKey) should only affect the response time. Similarly, using includeKey will affect the response time by increasing the amount of data transmitted over the network. Nesting a bunch of queries together using completion handers won't affect threads at all because the next query will not be executed until the first one has completed. Assuming that the "place" attribute you're including in the query is a pointer with valid data for createdBy it should be just fine

Comment: Maybe there could be an issue if createdBy is nil, but I'm not sure what the expected behavior is in that situation. Go back and try to narrow down your code one query at at time to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: I'd move this to chat but don't have the reputation to. I tested to see if Place or createdBy on Place were either undefined, nil, or pointing to an invalid object. All these cases the query returned quickly with just "(null)". Totally stuck.

Comment: Have you been able to narrow down which query is causing the problem, if any? The app may freeze for any number of reasons so we really need to find the root of the problem.

Comment: It is the news feed (code above). On startup I query for the news feed, the owner's "item collection", and messages. All with `findInBackgroundWithBlock:`. I log when the queries complete. The collection and messages always complete. The news feed only sometimes completes. When it doesn't complete (execute the block), the app will freeze with a few taps around the UI. No error is returned. The newsfeed query always completes if that is the only one, and also if the item collection query is there. It seems the message query if interfering with something...would you be willing to chat on Skype?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not really, I just totally removed Local Datastore for now and the speed is as expected. On looking at the GitHub repo "Issues" I see other complaints that Local Datastore is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out what was going on, but my solution was to fire my Messages query (a different class) only after the News Feed query returned. So far the app fires my queries fine with this setup. My item collection query can still fire asynchronously without problem. Somehow my News Feed and Messages query were interacting with each other (perhaps on backend).

PS. See comments for the discussion on this.